# Copying chars in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, char

I'm working on a caesar cipher sort of program to get my hands dirty but I'm stuck with the following piece of code:

```
char * encrypt(char *input) {
    int length = strlen(input);
    char *encrypted;

    encrypted = malloc(length+1);
    encrypted[0] = 0;

    int i;
    for(i=0; i < length; i++) {
        printf("%c\n", input[i]);
        if (i>0) {
            encrypted[i] = input[i];
        }
    }

    encrypted[length] = '\0';
    printf("Encrypted: %s\n", encrypted);
    return encrypted;
}
```

For now I'm just trying to figure out why I'm unable to copy the input char for char. The encrypted string at the end is shown empty. The `printf` statement of a `char` yields the correct value however.

What can be wrong with the code?

Comment: remove `encrypted[0] = 0` and remove `if (i > 0)`

Comment: Please describe *in the question* the behaviour you are seeing and how that differs from what you expect.

Comment: The first to learn after compiling and running a hello world example in C is to to learn how to use the debugger. With help of your debugger you will be able to find out that c strings are 0 terminated. Due to your line ``encrypted[0] = 0`` and the fact that you never change that value in your loop (``if(i > 0)...``) you see an empty string in your last printf output.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help! I thought I read I had to initialise the array with a 0 on the first element. After re-reading my C book I now realise I misread that part. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You're not copying the first character of the string (at index 0).  You DO set that character to 0 (NUL), so when you print `encrypted` as a string, it looks like it has a zero length.

Remove the `if (i>0)` test and copy the character unconditionally.  You can also remove the `encrypted[0] = 0;` line as you're going to overwrite it with the first character of the string.

Answer (score 1):

You already got the answer, just to elaborate on the *expectation* part, let me add my two cents.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.1, for a `%s` conversion specifier, with `printf()`, the expected type of argument is

> `s`
>
> If no `l` length modifier is present, the argument shall be a pointer to the initial
>   element of an array of character type. Characters from the array are
>   written **up to (but not including) the terminating null character**. [...]

So, in case, the first element in null, it stops there.

In other words, the definition of a C-style *string* is, from `C11`, chapter §7.1.1

> A string is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null
>   character. [....]

So, bottom line, whenever you use an array which you expect to be a *string*, you need to make sure that

- There is a null-terminator in the array
- The "required" data is present before the null-terminator.

For example, an array with content like "abc\0def\0" is a perfectly valid *string* as per definition, but it may not suit your requirement, because the "def" part will be processed by no function expecting a *string*, as there is one null-terminator before that and they stop processing there.

---

Now, while looping over each element, you don't rely on the null-terminator anymore, so (as long as you're within the array bound), you'll get proper value for all the individual elements.

Answer (score 0):

It *appears* to be empty since you have a NUL-terminator as the first element. Did you really want `encrypted[0] = 0;`, and `if (i > 0) {`?

So the C-style string output functions will not print any of the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (i>0) {
              encrypted[i] = input[i];
```

The problem is here and your if should look like this

```
 if (i>=0) {
             encrypted[i] = input[i];
```

This if has not too much sense